# Alternative word for "less than or equal to"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction, word-request, word-meaning

I want to ask about the number of people whose ages are `less than or equal to 18`. It is important to be precise and mention that also this includes those whose ages equal to 18 (therefore `less than 18` is not suitable)

So I have this sentence:

> How many girls whose ages are less than or equal to 18 do you have?

Is there any better way to describe this age range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

> How many girls whose ages are less than or equal to 18 do you have?

You could say:

> How many girls do you have who are aged 18 or under?

or

> How many girls do you have who are under 19 years of age?

Answer (score 0):

The shorter alternative to “less than or equal to” is “not greater than”. This isn’t as common in everyday speech as the former, but it’s used plenty in law, engineering or other technical contexts that value accuracy and brevity over readability to laymen.